# number of css ids are possible to add to css?

Tags: html, css

I have a html file that contains three divs:

```
<div id="rooms"></div>
<div id="chatters"></div>
<div id="chat-console"></div>
```

and i want to define several style to each and some styles are the same. So i created the following css:;

```
#chatters, #rooms { width: 100px, margin: 0 1em 0 0; float: left; list-style: none; }
#chatters, #chat-console, #rooms { height: 300px; overflow: auto; padding: 1%;}
#chat-console, #chatters, #chat-form, #rooms input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

in the third css line there is also one chat form div but there is no concern to the case.

Problem: my `rooms` div doesn't get the border line specified in the third css specification. Although `chat-console` and `chatters` do.

When i inspect the code in the browser this is what i get for `rooms` div:

```
#chatters, #chat-console, #rooms {height: 300px; overflow: auto; padding: 1%;}
#chatters, #rooms { width: 100px; margin: 0px 1em 0px 0px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;}
```

but never see the line `#chat-console, #chatters, #chat-form, #rooms input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }` where it is set the border for the div.

Although when i inspect chatters and chat-console div i have the css line `#chat-console, #chatters, #chat-form, #rooms input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }`

Why is this happening? i set the rooms div to have that css rule as well. Why does it not appear?
Is there a limit in the number of ids to add before the rule and i exceeded that number so it stopped working?

Comment: `#rooms input[type=text]` specifies that the css apply to that element within the #rooms element. It wont apply to room directly. You would also be better off using classes to do all this.

Comment: If there was a limit, it wouldn't work for `chatters` either. I'm thinking there is a conflict happening somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#rooms input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

Does not set the border for the #rooms div, it only sets the border on the **input** that is a child of the #rooms div.

```
#chat-console, #chatters, #chat-form, #rooms { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

for the border on the div is what you are after I think.

or

```
#chat-console, #chatters, #chat-form, #rooms, #rooms input[type=text] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

if you want the border on the div **and** the input.

Comment: this solves the problem ofc but the code i posted is actually setting those borders for the other divs and i dont have to create another css rule.